# How to ignore certain characters while writing to file using tee command

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have a zsh script that's piping the output to a file, i.e

```
<command here> | tee -a testFile
```

my issue is that some of the outputs from the command are the characters "[]". I do not want these written to my testFile, but anything else should be written to the file (e.g. ["Hello"]). How can I go about filtering what gets written to my testFile? TIA

I want the output to be like:

```
["Hello"]
["World"]
["One"]
["Two"]
```

.. etc

but currently I'm getting something like this:

```
[]
[]
[]
["Hello"]
["World"]
[]
[]
["One"]
[]
["Two"]
```

So far I've tried:

```
<command here> | sed -E 's/\[|\]//g' | tee -a testFile
```

but this also leads to an incorrect output of (note [] being replaced by nothing and then that being added to the file as a new line):

```
["Hello"]
["World"]


["One"]

["Two"]
```

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input (ie, several lines of output generated by `<command here>` (including strings to remove vs keep), the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the characters "[]" to be removed appear alone in the line without
any other leading/trailing characters (as described in the provided example),
would you please try:

```
<command here> | sed -nE '/^\[]$/!p' | tee -a testFile
```

Output:

```
["Hello"]
["World"]
["One"]
["Two"]
```